# Generate React Components

Tags: reactjs, npm

After Typing `npm install --save-dev create-react-component-folder` it runs the script but as far as i can tell never makes the folder does anyone know where this folder would be located thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'npx crcf myComponent' is what's needed to create the folder.

Answer (score -1):

use npx crcf myComponent as the script runs globally from terminal
[as in description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-component-folder)

```
$ npm install --save-dev create-react-component-folder
$ npx crcf myComponent
```